# PHP Getting the SUM from two values from a complicated string

Tags: php, sum

im kinda new to programming so im sorry if this is a simple question.

I got the following two strings.

`<Programvalue>52,45 €<Januari>'`

`<Programvalue>21,18 €<February>'`

I want to get the two values and get the sum of them.
I tried the following

```
$str1 = "<Programvalue>52,45 €<Januari>";
$str2 = "<Programvalue>21,18 €<February>";

$st1 = explode('>',$str1,0);
$st2 = explode('>',$str2,0);

$s1 = str_replace(" €","",$st1);
$s2 = str_replace(" €","",$st2);

$sum1 = implode( "", $s1 );
$sum2 = implode( "", $s2 );


$sum = $sum1 + $sum2;

echo $sum;
```

But the output keeps being 0

What do I have to do to get the output 73.63 ?

Thanks for all the help and I'm sorry if this question is really stupid. tbh i kinda feel stupid for not finding a solution myself :(

Answer (score 2):

Simply put:

```
   $str1 = "<Programvalue>52,45 €<Januari>";
   $str2 = "<Programvalue>21,18 €<February>";

   $st1 = str_replace(array('€', ','), array('', '.'), strip_tags($str1));
   $st2 = str_replace(array('€', ','), array('', '.'), strip_tags($str2));

   $sum = $st1 + $st2;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for using strip tags. :)